# complex integrals springing from IMO question?

Tags: complex-analysis, contest-math

I was looking at problem $A2$ here: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2006SL.pdf

The comment following $A2$ suggests that complex contours lead to a nice expression, but I don’t see the connection. It may have to do with the residue theorem.

Comment: By the way, perhaps because the elementary solution is truly elementary, or because complex analysis has some relevance (and goes beyond the confines of standard IMO questions), the question never made it to the final 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the comment following A2 we know 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k=\frac{z}{\log (1-z)},\quad (|z|<1)$$
where the branch of $\log(1-z)$ is chosen so that $\log 1 =0$ of course. 
We can rewrite this as 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k=\frac{z}{\log (z-1)-i\pi},$$
where the branch of $\log(z-1)$ is chosen so that $0\le \operatorname{Im}\,\log (z-1)<2\pi$.
Dividing both sides by $z^{n+1}$ we have $$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^{k-n-1}=\frac{1}{z^n(\log (z-1)-i\pi)}$$
and hence the residue therem yields 
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}  \frac{dz}{z^n(\log (z-1)-i\pi)} \quad (r<1).$$
Now we consider the keyhole-shaped contour consisting of
1. the horizontal line segment $I_1$ from $1+i\varepsilon $ to $\sqrt{R^2-\varepsilon ^2}+i\varepsilon $;
2. the circular arc $C_R$ of radius $R$ traced counterclockwise from $\sqrt{R^2-\varepsilon ^2 } +i\varepsilon $ to $\sqrt{R^2-\varepsilon ^2 } -i\varepsilon$;
3. the horizontal line segment $I_2$ from $\sqrt{R^2-\varepsilon ^2}-i\varepsilon $ to $1-i\varepsilon $;
4. the semi-circle $C_\varepsilon $ of radius $\varepsilon $ traced clockwise from $1-i\varepsilon $ to $1+i\varepsilon $.

Then we have \begin{align}
a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{I_1}+\int_{C_R}+\int_{I_2}+\int_{C_\varepsilon }\right)  \frac{dz}{z^n(\log (z-1)-i\pi)} ,\tag{1}\end{align}
since the integrand is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (\{0\}\cup [1,\infty))$.
Note that \begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{I_2} \frac{dz}{z^n(\log (z-1)-i\pi)}&=\int_R^1 \frac{dx}{x^n(\log (x-1)+2i\pi-i\pi)}\\
&=\int_R^1 \frac{dx}{x^n(\log (x-1)+i\pi)}.\end{align}
Therefore letting $R \to \infty$, $\varepsilon \to 0$ in $(1)$, we have 
\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^n\left(\log (x-1)-i\pi\right)}+\int_\infty^1 \frac{dx}{x^n\left(\log (x-1)+i\pi\right)}\right)\\
&=\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^n\left(\log^2(x-1)+\pi^2\right)},
\end{align}
since integrals along $C_\varepsilon $ and $C_R$ tend to $0$.